# How to call a method once an element has loaded using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I need to call a method `mymethod()` when the calendar loads. In the documentation I didn't find anything. Initially I am displaying month view and no events.

How do I call `mymethod()` after displaying the calendar..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to call the mymethod function after everything has loaded right? If so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

// everything has loaded

function mymethod {

// function logic goes here

}

mymethod();

});
```